# python - get the session user

Tags: python, windows

I'm running the same Python script for different users on my PC (Windows 10). This script has to get the user who is actually logged in. For example `getpass.getuser()` isn't working because it just returns the user for which the Python script is running. How can I get this? Thanks for help!

Comment: What do you mean where the `python user is running`?

Comment: No which user is actually logged in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of *Run as...* is to mimic the environment of another user so, naturally, when you query for the username (which essentially gets you the value of `%USERNAME%` env. variable) you'll get the one under which you're running the script.

To get the currently logged in user, you'll have prod the current session, and to do that, at the very least, you'll have to query WMIC (or access the Win32 API directly). Something like:

```
import subprocess

def get_session_user():
    res = subprocess.check_output(["WMIC", "ComputerSystem", "GET", "UserName"],
                                  universal_newlines=True)
    _, username = res.strip().rsplit("\n", 1)
    return username.rsplit("\\", 1)
```

Beware that this will return a tuple containing both the system/domain of the currently logged-in user and the username itself, so call it as:

```
system, username = get_session_user()
```

To get both.

Comment: If you have PyWin32 installed you could also use  `username = win32ts.WTSQuerySessionInformation(None, -1, win32ts.WTSUserName)`.

Comment: Or use ctypes if PyWin32 isn't installed: `wtsapi32 = ctypes.WinDLL('wtsapi32', use_last_error=True);` `WTSUserName = 5;` `pbuf = ctypes.c_wchar_p();` `n = ctypes.c_ulong();` `success = wtsapi32.WTSQuerySessionInformationW(None, -1, WTSUserName, ctypes.byref(pbuf), ctypes.byref(n));` and then `if not success: raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error());` and finally `username = pbuf.value;` `wtsapi32.WTSFreeMemory(pbuf)`